# Access query fails when WHERE statement is added to subquery referencing ODBC link

Tags: sql, subquery, ms-access-2007

## Original post

Given two tables structured like this:

```
t1 (finished goods)      t2 (component parts)

sku  | desc  | fcst       sku  | part   | quant
0001 | Car   | 10000      0001 | wheel  | 4
0002 | Boat  | 5000       0001 | door   | 2
0003 | Bike  | 7500       0002 | hull   | 1
0004 | Shirt | 2500       0002 | rudder | 1
...  | ...   | ...        0003 | wheel  | 2
                          0005 | rotor  | 2
                          ...  | ...    | ...
```

I am trying to append wheel requirements to the forecast, while leaving all records in the forecast. My results would look like this:

```
sku  | desc  | fcst  | wheels | wheelfcst
0001 | Car   | 10000 | 4      | 40000
0002 | Boat  | 5000  |        |
0003 | Bike  | 7500  | 2      | 15000
0004 | Shirt | 2500  |        |
...  | ...   | ...   | ...    | ...
```

The most efficient way to go about this in my eyes is something like this query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.sku, 
    t1.desc, 
    t1.fcst, 
    q.quant as wheels, 
    t1.fcst * q.quant as wheelfcst
FROM
    t1 
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM t2
            WHERE part LIKE "wheel"
        )
        as q
    ON t1.sku = q.sku
```

The problem is that it gives a very elaborate `Invalid Operation.` error when ran.

If I remove the `WHERE` statement: I get the wheel parts as desired but I also pull door, hull, and rudder quantities.

If I move the `WHERE` statement to the main query (`WHERE q.part LIKE "wheel"`): I only see goods that contain wheels, but boats are then missing from the results.

I have considered a `UNION` statement, taking the results of the previously mentioned moving the `WHERE` out of the subquery (`WHERE q.part LIKE "wheel"`), but there doesn't seem to be a good way to grab every final item that doesn't have a wheel component because each `sku` can have anywhere from 0 to many components.

Is there something I'm overlooking in my desired query, or is this something requiring a `UNION` approach?

### EDIT #1 - To answer questions raised by Andre

[image: Screenshot of my personal issue.]

- The full error message is `Invalid operation.`
- `sku` is the primary key of `t1`, and there are 1426 records.
- `t2` contains ~446,000 records, the primary key is a composite of `sku` and `part`.
- The actual `WHERE` statement is a partial search. All "wheels" have the same suffix but different component item numbers.

Additionally, I am in Access 2007, it may be an issue related to software version.

Making the subquery into a temporary table works, but the goal is to avoid that procedure.

### EDIT #2 - A flaw in my environment

[image: My test case results]

I created a test scenario identical to the one I have posted here, and I get the same results as Andre. At this point, combining these results with the fact that the temporary table method does in fact work, I am led to believe that it is an issue with query complexity and record access. Despite the error message not being the typical `Query is too complex.` message.

### EDIT #3 - Digging deeper into "Complexity"

My next test will be to make the where clause simpler. Sadly, the systems I work on update at lunch each day and I currently cannot reach any data servers. I hope to update my progress at a later point today.

### EDIT #4 - Replacing the partial search

Ok, we're back from a meeting and ready to go. I've just ran six queries with three different `WHERE` clauses:

`WHERE part LIKE "*heel"` / `WHERE component_item LIKE "*SBP"` (Original large scale issue)
Works in small scale test, `Invalid operation` on large scale.

`WHERE part LIKE "wheel"` / `WHERE component_item LIKE "VALIDPART"` (Original small scale)
Works in small scale test, `Invalid operation` on large scale.

`WHERE part LIKE "wh33l"` / `WHERE component_item LIKE "NOTVALIDPART"`(Where statements that do not return any records)

```
Small Scale 
sku  | desc  | fcst  | wheels | wheelfcst
0001 | Car   | 10000 |        |
0002 | Boat  | 5000  |        |
0003 | Bike  | 10000 |        |
0004 | Shirt | 5000  |        |

Large Scale
sku  |description |forecast |component_item |dip_rate
#####|RealItem1   | ######  |               |
#####|RealItem2   | ######  |               |
#####|RealItem3   | ######  |               |
...  |...         | ...     |               |
```

**Tl;dr** The filter specifics did not make a difference unless the filter resulted in a subquery that returned 0 records.

### EDIT #5 - An interesting result

Under the idea of trying every possible solution and test everything I can, I made a local temporary table which contained every field and every record from `t2` (~25MB). Referencing this table instead of the ODBC link to `t2` works with the partial search query (`WHERE component_item LIKE "*SBP"`). I am updating the title of this question to reflect that the issue is specific to a linked table.

Comment: ... I trust you're using single quotes instead of double quotes in the where clause, right?

Comment: It makes no difference in Access actually. For better or for worse I'm not entirely sure. (I can't say I'm a big fan of the development platforms we have.)

Comment: To further elaborate, using ' ' instead of " " returns the same error, and the subquery runs fine on its own, returning a list of `sku | "wheel" | quant`.

Comment: Yeah, not sure- Your query looks good to me.  If I were in your shoes, I would probably try using a table variable in place of your subquery or other workarounds.  I don't see an issue with what you've laid out though.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: I think it is related to the left join. Access sometimes gives this error when using Left joins, try to replace it with an inner join to see if the error persists.

Comment: @haytem - `INNER JOIN` works, but has the same effect of placing the `WHERE` statement outside of the subquery.

Comment: I sense a problem in this line: `t1.fcst * q.quant as wheelfcst`. Might fail because of the null values. Try it without that line. If it works, you'll need another subquery

Comment: @MyBrainHurts error occurs without `t1.fcst * q.quant as wheelfcst`, good idea though.

Comment: `WHERE component_item LIKE '*SBP'` - that is a very expensive query, with the * at the beginning. In a table with 400k records, I think the error is Access's way of saying "I give up, too much data to process". Do you have an index on `t2.sku` to help with the join?

Comment: You might be on to something there, @Andre. I've updated the OP with an edit describing my test scenario results. They are identical to your results.

Comment: Some more notes and questions. 1. Does adding an index on `t2.sku` make any difference? (I'm not sure, since it's already part of the PK.) -- 2. The query `WHERE part LIKE "wheel"` would greatly profit from an index on `part`. But since that's not your use case, the point is moot. -- 3. Something worth trying: put the subquery into a separate query, and make the left join with that (not a temporary table, but a separate query).

Comment: @Andre, in response to 3: No change when the subquery is stored separately. I'll look into indexing tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A workaround

I have devised a set of queries that works by using one of my original hunches of a `UNION` statement. Hopefully this allows for anyone that stumbles across this issue to save a bit of time.

**Setting up the `UNION`**

My initial problem was with the idea that there was no way to select only wheel record and then join them to null records, because (using `t1` as an example) the Boat has parts in `t2`, but none of them are wheels. I had to first devise a method to see which products had wheels without using a filter.

My intermediary solution:

```
Query: t1haswheel
SELECT
    t1.sku, 
    t1.desc, 
    t1.fcst, 
    SUM(
        IF(
            t2.part = "wheel",
            1, 0
          ) as haswheel
FROM
    t1 
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM t2
            WHERE part LIKE "wheel"
        )
        as q
    ON t1.sku = q.sku
GROUP BY
    t1.sku, 
    t1.desc, 
    t1.fcst
```

This query returns every record from `t1` followed by a number based on the number of `wheel` records there are in the part list for that item number. If there are no records in `t2` with "wheel" in the field `part`, the query returns 0 for the record. This list is what I needed for the `UNION` statement in the original question.

**`UNION`-ing it all together**

At this point, all that is needed is a `UNION` which uses the summation field from the previous query (`haswheel`).

```
SELECT
    q1.sku, 
    q1.desc,
    q1.fcst,
    t2.quant,
    q1.fcst * t2.quant as wheelfcst
FROM 
    t1haswheel as q1
    LEFT JOIN t2
    ON q1.sku = t2.sku
WHERE 
    q1.haswheel > 0 AND
    t2.part = "wheel"

UNION ALL

SELECT
    q1.sku, 
    q1.desc,
    q1.fcst,
    null,
    null
FROM 
    t1haswheel as q1

WHERE q1.haswheel = 0
```

This pulls in the correct results from records with wheels, and then attaches the records without wheels, while never using the `WHERE` statement in a subquery which references an ODBC linked table:

```
sku  | desc  | fcst  | wheels | wheelfcst
0001 | Car   | 10000 | 4      | 40000
0003 | Bike  | 7500  | 2      | 15000
...  | ...   | ...   | ...    | ...
0002 | Boat  | 5000  |        |
0004 | Shirt | 2500  |        |
...  | ...   | ...   | ...    | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the sample data to Access 2010 and ran the query, it worked without problems.

[image: datasheet view of query]

What is the full error message you get? ("very elaborate Invalid Operation.")

How many records are in your tables?

Is `sku` primary key in `t1`?

In any case, I suggest changing the subquery to:

```
SELECT sku, quant
FROM t2
WHERE part = "wheel"
```

`LIKE` is only needed for partial searches.

Comment: Your response makes me think it might be related to Access 2007. I'll create a test scenario on my end and update.

Comment: Additionally, I've answered your questions in an update to the original post.